# How to amplify rust sinewave?

Tags: rust

I am trying to play a direction audio sound but I cannot seem to amplify the sinewave

```
fn main() {
    use std::thread::sleep;
    use std::time::Duration;
    use ambisonic::{rodio, AmbisonicBuilder};

    let scene = AmbisonicBuilder::default().build();
    let source = rodio::source::SineWave::new(440).amplify(0.5);
    let mut sound = scene.play_at(source, [50.0, 1.0, 0.0]);

// move sound from right to left
    sound.set_velocity([-10.0, 0.0, 0.0]);
    for i in 0..1000 {
        sound.adjust_position([50.0 - i as f32 / 10.0, 1.0, 0.0]);
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
    }
    sound.set_velocity([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]);

}
```

this code throws this error:

```
let source = rodio::source::SineWave::new(440).scale_amplitude(0.5);
  |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `SineWave`
```

It works fine if I remove the amplify function
Does anyone know why I have this error?

I'm looking for this sine wave to by amplified.

Comment: It probably is due to the 'amplify()' method not returning the SineWave object? Try calling the method the line after the new SineWave()

Comment: I added:
source.amplify(0.5); to the next line 

but it threw:
source.amplify(0.5);
    |            ^^^^^^^ method not found in `SineWave`

Comment: Did I misunderstand what you meant?

Comment: No, then I wasn't right.

Comment: you probably need to import the source trait `use rodio::Source;`

Comment: that leads to this error:
 I: rodio::Source<Item = f32> + Send + 'static,
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Ambisonic::play_at`

Answer (score 0):

[ambisonic](https://docs.rs/ambisonic/latest/ambisonic/) currently has version 0.13 of [rodio](https://docs.rs/rodio/latest/rodio/) as a dependency. If you have both `rodio` and `ambisonic` listed in your `Cargo.toml`, then the imported traits may conflict with each other.

Since `ambisonic` reexports `rodio`, if you import the `Source` trait as:

```rs
    use ambisonic::rodio::Source;
```

then the code compiles:

```rs
fn main() {
    use std::thread::sleep;
    use std::time::Duration;
    use ambisonic::{rodio, AmbisonicBuilder};
    use ambisonic::rodio::Source;

    let scene = AmbisonicBuilder::default().build();
    let source = rodio::source::SineWave::new(440).amplify(0.5);
    let mut sound = scene.play_at(source, [50.0, 1.0, 0.0]);

    // move sound from right to left
    sound.set_velocity([-10.0, 0.0, 0.0]);
    for i in 0..1000 {
        sound.adjust_position([50.0 - i as f32 / 10.0, 1.0, 0.0]);
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
    }
    sound.set_velocity([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]);
}
```